# Cart system is bugging out when multiple products are removed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a store for my game. The idea is that the checkout is loaded concurrently to the user creating his decision on products. This is done like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var cart = [];

  $('.inc-btn').click(function() {
    var itemid = $(this).attr('itemid');
    if (cart[itemid] != undefined) {
      cart[itemid] = ++cart[itemid];
    } else {
      cart[itemid] = 1;
    }

    $('#total-' + itemid).text(cart[itemid]);

    updateCheckout(itemid, $(this).attr('cost'), cart[itemid]);

    $.post('/store/cart', {
      cart: itemid,
      quantity: cart[itemid]
    }, function(r) {
      return;
    });
  });

  $('.dinc-btn').click(function() {
    var itemid = $(this).attr('itemid');
    if (cart[itemid] != undefined && cart[itemid] != 0) {
      cart[itemid] = --cart[itemid];
    } else {
      cart[itemid] = 0;
    }

    $('#total-' + itemid).text(cart[itemid]);

    updateCheckout(itemid, $(this).attr('cost'), cart[itemid]);

    $.post('/store/cart', {
      cart: itemid,
      quantity: cart[itemid]
    }, function(r) {
      return;
    });
  });

  checkout = [];

  function updateCheckout(id, cost, quantity) {
    if (quantity != 0) {
      checkout[id] = cost * quantity;
    } else {
      if (checkout[id] != undefined) {
        var i = checkout.indexOf(checkout[id]);
        checkout.splice(i, i);
      }
    }

    $('#checkout').text('');

    var total = 0;

    checkout.forEach(function(k, v) {
      $('#checkout').append('<tr><td>' + v + '</td><td>$' + k.toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>');
      total = k + total;
    });

    $('#total-cost').text(total.toFixed(2));

    /*$.get('/store/stripe/' + total.toFixed(2).replace('.', ''), function(stripe) {
      $('#stripe').html(stripe);
    });*/

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Item</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Add to Cart</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>995</td>
            <td>Gold<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/6964.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>1.00</td>
            <td>1000000</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="1.00" itemid='995' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="1.00" itemid='995' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-995'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">2</th>
            <td>14484</td>
            <td>Dragon Claws<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/13652.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>10.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="10.00" itemid='14484' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="10.00" itemid='14484' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-14484'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">3</th>
            <td>20002</td>
            <td>Ragefire Boots<img src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/runescape2/images/0/0f/Ragefire_boots_detail.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>8.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="8.00" itemid='20002' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="8.00" itemid='20002' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-20002'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">4</th>
            <td>607</td>
            <td>$10 Scroll<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/607.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>10.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="10.00" itemid='607' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="10.00" itemid='607' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-607'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">5</th>
            <td>608</td>
            <td>$50 Scroll<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/608.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="50.00" itemid='608' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="50.00" itemid='608' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-608'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">6</th>
            <td>11694</td>
            <td>Armadyl Godsword<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/11802.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>8.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="8.00" itemid='11694' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="8.00" itemid='11694' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-11694'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody style="border-top: none;">
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">7</th>
            <td>20555</td>
            <td>Dragon Warhammer<img src='https://www.osrsbox.com/osrsbox-db/items-icons/13576.png' style='max-width: 40px; width: 100%; height: 40px; margin-left: 10%;'></td>
            <td>50.00</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>
              <button cost="50.00" itemid='20555' class='inc-btn'>+</button> or
              <button cost="50.00" itemid='20555' class='dinc-btn'>-</button>
            </td>
            <td><span id='total-20555'>0</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 5%;">Cart Summary</h2>
      <p style="text-align: center;">
        Welcome to ExoScape's store, where you can purchase in-game items. Start by telling us your in-game Username so we can add funds.
      </p>
      <table class="table table-striped table-dark">
        <thead>

          <tr>
            <!--<th scope="col">#</th>-->
            <th scope="col">Item ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="checkout" style="border-top: none;">

        </tbody>
      </table>
      $<span id="total-cost">0.00</span>
      <button type "button" id="stripe">Pay btn would be here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The generic concept works fine, however, if you add multiple (add all products a few times) and then remove them all (put all totals to 0), it bugs and is left with an item ID that doesn't exist in my store.

I have tried debugging this to find why its doing this but cannot find the reason. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Without debugging the code for you, the pattern seems to be that you are numerically subtracting the item ID from other item IDs.  To observe, add one of your first item, one of your second item, then subtract one of the first item and see how the item IDs in the cart update.  Somewhere in your logic you're performing math on identifiers, instead of just using them to identify the record.

Comment: Thankyou! I'll look into this @David

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @David for pointing out that some how the identifiers where being calculated rather than the property.

I rewrote the logic to use an array of objects to make it easier. This now works with no unexpected behaviors.

```
var cart        = [];
var discount    = 0;
var total       = 0;

var incBtn      = $('.inc-btn');
var dincBtn     = $('.dinc-btn');

var checkout    = $('#checkout');
var stripe      = $('#stripe');

var cartSummary = $('#total-cost');

incBtn.click(function() {
    var id      = $(this).attr('itemid');
    var cost    = $(this).attr('cost');

    var item    = cart.filter(function(x) {
        return x.id == id;
    });

    if(item.length > 0) {
        $('#total-' + id).text(++cart[cart.indexOf(item[0])].quantity)
        updateCheckout();
        return;
    }

    cart.push({ id: id, quantity: 1, cost: cost});
    $('#total-' + id).text(cart[cart.length -1].quantity);
    updateCheckout();
});

dincBtn.click(function() {
    var id      = $(this).attr('itemid');

    var item = cart.filter(function(x) {
        return x.id == id;
    });

    if(item.length > 0) {
        if(cart[cart.indexOf(item[0])].quantity > 0) {
            $('#total-' + id).text(--cart[cart.indexOf(item[0])].quantity);
            updateCheckout();
            return;
        }
        $('#total-' + id).text(0);
        updateCheckout();
    }
});

function updateCheckout() {
    checkout.text('');
    total = 0;

    cart.forEach(function(item) {
        checkout.append('<tr><td>' + item.id + '</td><td>$' + (item.quantity * item.cost).toFixed(2) + '</td></tr>');
        total    = (item.quantity * item.cost) + total;
    });

    cartSummary.text(total.toFixed(2));
}
```